# Show FTP Server response code in SFTP batch process (PSFTP.exe)

Tags: vbscript, ftp, cmd, sftp

Is there a way to display/output FTP server response code in PSFTP.exe?

FTP Server response code example:

`226 Transfer OK`

`200    Command okay`

My code:

`psftp.exe username@hostname -pw password -v -b batch_file > output_file 2>&1`

batch_file:

```
put some_file
quit
```

Output_file:

```
Looking up host "....."
Connecting to ..... port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.9p1
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.60_(Centrify_GSS_1.4)
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 1024 ....
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username ....
Sent .....
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Started a shell/command
Sent EOF message
Server sent command exit status 0
Disconnected: All channels closed
Connected to ......
Remote working directory is ....
local:some_file => remote: some_file_path_on_server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting to an [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) server, not an [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) server, so you don't get FTP server status codes. Although similar in name the [SSH File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) is fundamentally different from FTP.

Comment: Thanks, I know that they are COMPLETELY different protocol, just wondering if any SFTP client can "pretend" the server respond as a FTP.

Comment: No. And there's no reason they should either. Of course you could build a wrapper script around `psftp` and try to "translate" the log, but that would be rather pointless.